# SSRS Scorecard in visual studios 2012

Tags: reporting-services, pie-chart, ssrs-2012

[image: SSRS_scorecard_formatting_issue]

hello community. I'm currently building a scorecard that looks like the attached.

I can get the data to appear as simple text but how do I get these values out like attached.

Results lead me to putting labels on the outside. Sure. But how do i still put them in a line below each other.

> My question is:
>   1) is the attached format possible?
>   if not
>   2) Can I do a line from label to outside and put additional fields one below
>   another to give some kind of desired effect. Right now pie chart has 5
>   metrics its measuring (resulting in 5 pieces of pie). Over time there
>   is going to be a metric parameter showing up to as many (7 max) pieces
>   of pie.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
& Environment.NewLine()
```

fixed the issue for me to be able to render each metric by itself with various attribute and or calculations.

Design #1 was not a possible solution given SSRS's limitations.